# Converting JSON file with different types of nested data into one dataframe

Tags: r, json

I have a JSON file that looks as such:

```
 library(jsonlite)
    
  test_file <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datacfb123/testdata/main/test_file_lp.json")
```

If you open up `test_file` in R, you can see it looks as such:

[image]

The problem arises from the `latestPosts` data where some columns contain the data I need, but others don't. If you open up the subdata for username3, you will see two columns titled `locationName` and `locationId`, like screen shot below:

[image]

But the nested data for `username1` and `username2` does not contain those fields, which is fine. `username1` has nested data under `latestPosts` that doesn't have what we need, while `username2` has no data.

I am trying to write a script that captures the two location columns from whoever has them, while still keeping the original three columns that are in all of them. So the final dataframe would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is a simple helper function that can be applied using `map()`

```
f <- function(lp) {
  keys = c("locationName", "locationId")
  if(all(keys %in% names(lp))) lp[keys] %>% filter(!is.na(locationName))
  else setNames(data.frame(NA_character_, NA_character_),keys)
}

test_file %>%
  mutate(latestPosts = map(latestPosts,f)) %>%
  unnest(latestPosts)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 5
  username  fullName biography                             locationName              locationId     
  <chr>     <chr>    <chr>                                 <chr>                     <chr>          
1 username1 user 1   "⋘ ＴＲＹ ＡＧＡＩＮ ＬＡＴＥＲ... ⋙" NA                        NA             
2 username2 user2    "@tititima_d  real page \U0001f601"   NA                        NA             
3 username3 user 3   "cvg — baq \nsailin’ over saturn ♡"   Muelle De Puerto Colombia 742454235936668
4 username3 user 3   "cvg — baq \nsailin’ over saturn ♡"   Bogotá D.C, Colombia      100109272081380
5 username3 user 3   "cvg — baq \nsailin’ over saturn ♡"   Charlotte, North Carolina 213141085      
6 username3 user 3   "cvg — baq \nsailin’ over saturn ♡"   Kings Island              786647559      
7 username3 user 3   "cvg — baq \nsailin’ over saturn ♡"   Krohn Conservatory        214700679
```

Comment: Yes! This does exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyr::unnest()` to get all columns from all dataframes. Then do a grouped `dplyr::summarize()` to keep all non-`NA` values for your columns of interest, or else a single `NA` row if there are no non-`NA` values for a group.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

test_file %>% 
  unnest(latestPosts, keep_empty = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(username, fullName, biography) %>% 
  summarize(across(
    c(locationName, locationId), 
    ~ { if (all(is.na(locationName) & is.na(locationId))) NA else .x[!is.na(.x)] },
  )) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 7 × 5
  username  fullName biography                             locationName              locationId     
  <chr>     <chr>    <chr>                                 <chr>                     <chr>          
1 username1 user 1   "⋘ ＴＲＹ ＡＧＡＩＮ ＬＡＴＥＲ... ⋙" NA                        NA             
2 username2 user2    "@tititima_d  real page \U0001f601"   NA                        NA             
3 username3 user 3   "cvg — baq \nsailin’ over saturn ♡"   Muelle De Puerto Colombia 742454235936668
4 username3 user 3   "cvg — baq \nsailin’ over saturn ♡"   Bogotá D.C, Colombia      100109272081380
5 username3 user 3   "cvg — baq \nsailin’ over saturn ♡"   Charlotte, North Carolina 213141085      
6 username3 user 3   "cvg — baq \nsailin’ over saturn ♡"   Kings Island              786647559      
7 username3 user 3   "cvg — baq \nsailin’ over saturn ♡"   Krohn Conservatory        214700679
```